# unable to access WHM and SSH/root after a configuration in Host Access Control

Tags: google

I added my IP (like 172.32.1.0/255.255.255.0) to allow access for ssh, whm and cpanel in WHM -> Host Access Control. Then, I added all IP to deny access for them. However, after saved changes, I lost access all of them. Now, If I try to login WHM, I see that:

HTTP error 401

You do not have permission to access this page.

Also, I cannot access SSH. I don't know what to do. If I restart server, will the problem be solved?

Comment: You are likely going to have to get your hosting service to sort this out.

Answer (score 1):

No. Restarting won't solve the issue. It will just restart the server. Somehow you will have to reset your server. For that contact your hosting company.